# Re-bending a bent plastic figure to stand up straight

Tags: plastic

I have a plastic miniature person (an archer) from a board game, but she was unfortunately bent either during packaging or during initial molding. She leans WAY over...

[image]

I put her in a bowl of very hot water which made her pliable. I straightened her out and put a clamp on her to keep her in the right position while she cooled down. She seemed to stay upright, but after an hour or two she has migrated back down to her bent position.

How can I bend her to be straight and keep her there permanently?

Comment: This needs more details, like what kind of plastic the figurine is made from. Additionally, we are about handmade arts and crafts, rather than a general repair forum, so it's only tangentially on topic anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try to repeat the procedure, but bend it in the opposite direction, until it cools down (or even more, to be sure). While it will tend to come back, it might stop (close) to the vertical position.

You may need to repeat for a few times. Do not force it too much, as it can break.